# Drag event inverts in landscape mode

Tags: c#, unity, mobile

I am developing an car game for android  with an UI steering wheel to control the car. I'm following [Answer example](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/touchscreen-steering-wheel-rotation-example-mouse-supported.196741/) for the wheel rotation. This is the code to rotate the wheel.

```
rectT.localEulerAngles = Vector3.back * wheelAngle;
```

This code working completely fine in unity and in the portrait mode of actual device.

But in the landscape modeof actual devices , the rotation get inverted. 
Please help me to solve this problem. 
Thank you

Comment: Check ScreenOrientation's enum documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html . From here you can decide the criteria of which direction to assign on drag's event.

Answer (score -1):

You could maybe detect the orientation of the device and if its in landscape mode, it spins in the other direction.

```
if (portraitMode) {
   rectT.localEulerAngles = Vector3.back * wheelAngle;
} else {
   if (landscapeMode) {
       rectT.localEulerAngles = Vector3.forward * wheelAngle;
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer lacks information about how one detects landscape or portrait mode in Unity.